# Adding more than one attachment to point layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments

I have been requested to modify a point layer to allow attachments for photos, and ideally add more than one attachment for photos over time. For example, when revisiting a site the following year the users would like the ability to see old photos taken at that point and add a new one.

If this is possible to do in ArcGIS Online (AGOL), then how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Attachments are a 1:Many relationship, meaning, for each of your points you can have as many attachments as you want. You do not need to do anything beyond enabling attachments on the Feature Service. You can continue adding (or deleting) attachments at anytime. You would update the existing feature, instead of creating a new one.

You can follow these [instructions to enable editing and attachments](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3FA256DBA3D94BBB9F21CA1481E656E3).

[image]